# amazon s3 archival schedule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-glacier

I could see that , S3 will evaluate the lifecycle policies and will archive objects in Glacier every date, is there a way to find out the exact timings?

How to find or set the glacier vault to which the files are archived from s3 using life cycle transformation ?

I don't see an option to choose the vault in the Life cycle configuration .

Answer (score 0):

The **AWS S3 metrics request** can be configured to capture the actions performed on the S3 bucket.

[Metric config documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/configure-metrics.html)

Also, metrics are captured for each action. You can see the metric for `DeleteRequests` only (i.e. when the S3 object is archived into Glacier and the object is deleted from bucket).

[Cloudwatch monitoring](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html)